# Efficient and effective return of mongodb results containing images

Tags: python, image, mongodb, flask

The issue is returning results from mongodb with bson images encoded. I decided that I would get away from having images being pulled from a directory as images and see how I could get along by putting everything into mongodb. However the problem now is thus:

1. I'm returning a lot of results.
2. Those results need an image pulled from mongo.
3. A lot of those images are actually identical.

I'm using lots of memory, instead of letting the browser perform the caching by using a static link to the right image in my HTML results, I'm locating and displaying each of those images in my results with the following:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{result._img}}" title="{{result.name}}" width="80px" align="center">
```

So I'm guessing that while much of the src is the same, we cannot get the same degree of performance if we were just using a simple:

```
<img src="/static/images/myimage.png" title="{{result.name}}" width="80px" align="center">
```

The number of results run's into their thousands, the actual number of distinct images are in the 10's. Rather than re-engineer the way I pull the images, is there something I can do to minimize my total data load?

I am producing on flask and the results are generated in the following way:

1. Get all images from image collection, put into image dictionary
2. Get all results (without images)
3. Loop through each result, and perform a join, but pulling image from the image dictionary, add this to the result.
4. return render_template

Comment: Why don't you cache those 10-ish images on your local webserver ? Your service logic then only has to figure out which image it needs to load. You could store md5 hashes of each image in MongoDB to make this even faster

Comment: Or just create a separate endpoint to actually just retrieve the images. If they are called often enough then the browser cache is going to help performance. So use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this with just MongoDB, I would suggest:

1. Creating a second collection to actually store your images. Do not store them as blobs with your primary records. Your image collection will have only two fields, `image_blob` and `image_hash`. Lets call this collection `images`.
2. When you insert a record, create the `image_hash` for the image blob, and check to see if there's a duplicate record already in the `images` collection.
3. Create a new endpoint on your server that looks like: `localhost/api/images/<image_hash>.png` Ensure that your caching headers are properly set to cache this forever, since if the image changes you'll have a new URL anyways.

Comment: OK, Thanks, its looks like browser cache it is. I shall create some endpoints for the images. This seems sensible.